# How can I create a zfs container docker data, I have also created multiple container for my developer environment

Tags: ubuntu, docker, redundancy, zfs

I want to create a zfs docker I need a little help, I work on ubuntu, I create 3 containers for my environment in docker. Need to use this file system with data redundancy.

Comment: unclear what are you asking. fix your mispells

Comment: i have to create a container wich must be hosted on a ZFS file system. i have to configure a new 
container repository of 50 GB based on it.
The developers will handle after your work the tuning of this element if needed.

Comment: Up needs some help please :)

Comment: If the container does not need to mount or change your actual hosts underlying ZFS, then you should not have to worry about doing anything  different as you would with any other filesystem as Docker will use AUFS on top of that. You can actually have Docker use ZFS instead of AUFS, but I do not believe that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 4):

I do not have a definitive answer, but I do know that in order to mount;

- The container would need **`CAP_SYS_ADMIN`**, and perhaps **`CAP_MKNOD`**.

  You can specifiy this explicitly in Docker 1.2+ using **`--cap-add=""`**
  (`man capabilities` might give you an idea of what can be done if you know what you need.)

  Or simply:  `--priveleged=True` (less explicit, *less* secure)

  `docker run --cap-add="CAP_SYS_ADMIN" --cap-add="CAP_MKNOD" -i -t -v /mount/from/host:/container/mount/point --name="MYCONTAINER" repo/name /bin/bash`
- SE Linux Security Context:

  To make your data volume aware of SELINUX Security Type (allow
  writing

  to external volumes).
- `chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /var/db`

  Where `/var/db` would be your mount point (ie; `/mount/from/host` from eg above)

*I would also read about those who successfully did the same using [GlusterFS](http://blog.gluster.org/category/learning/), or [this](http://neependra.net/?p=1048), or anything using FUSE, as I suspect they would be restricted in similar ways.*

This answer is not super-specific, but neither was your question :)

***Edit:****This answer assumed the OP was asking how to use docker with ZFS (instead of AUFS). [Docker's ZFS driver](https://github.com/gurjeet/docker/tree/zfs_driver) support is still a work in progress at this point. To answer OP's question, I would say to just build the container as you normally would with any other FS.*

Comment: I can post my poject statement i don't understand this statement

Comment: Zfs driver is merged into docker since some versions.

Answer (score 0):

Florian,

1. Are you asking how to create a docker container with ZFS as a backend?

   In this case there is this docker fork. But I am not sure if this is compatible with a non-zfs docker host on another system.

   [docker-zfs on github](https://github.com/cloudbees/docker-zfs)
2. If you only need ZFS for it`s features like COW and snapshots just create a dataset and create the container inside it

   `zfs create zfs_pool_name/docker_container_name`
3. jRadds approach flies right over my head but it is a great starting point for me as well ;)

   Ah, now I get it. Linux kernel capabilities are meant for fine tuning access instead of using chroot as to limit the extent of how much the system gets compromised.

   [CAP_SYS_ADMIN: the new root](http://lwn.net/Articles/486306/)

   Hope that helps

Comment: I need to create three container like that 
Website_Dev
Debian  Squeeze 1  512 MB  
apache2,  build-¬‐ essential,  php5,    mysql-¬‐server-¬‐5.5,    openssh-¬‐server ,Apache  port 8000, MySQL port 1500    
and : You  must be able to  create those images without doing    anything    manually    inside    the    container,    like    installation,    configuration    and    additional    changes.    All    of    those    provision    stages    must    be    done    automatically.    
Once  images created,  developers  should  be  able    to    instantiate containers and push their code

Comment: Florian, this comment does not even mention ZFS. I thought you wanted a container that can mount the hosts ZFS. You need to start another thread with your actual question after you have attempted to solve this. Check out the Docker hub for an image to use. Like this one perhaps: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/eboraas/apache-php/